# how load image address from web service in android?

Tags: android, imageview, retrofit, picasso

i wrote a web service with java that save image address in my pc.

now i want pars that image in android with use from **Retrofit** and **Picasso** lib.

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ChordEntity>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ChordEntity>> call, Response<List<ChordEntity>> response) {
            List<ChordEntity> entities = response.body();
            for (ChordEntity entity : entities) {
                textView.setText(entity.getId());
                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(entity.getImage()).into(imageView);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ChordEntity>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

`entity.getImage()` store image address in pc but does not show in `imageView`..

Comment: Which version of Picasso are you using.?

Comment: @UmangBurman 2.5.2

Comment: Okay, are you getting values in entity.getImage()?

Comment: @UmangBurman in entity.getImage() exist image address in my pc

Comment: You need to put this line: `log.d("image: ", ""+entity.getImage());` and see in log whether you are getting a value in your log. Put this code in for loop in on response.

Comment: @UmangBurman _image: C:\Users\Amir251\Downloads\Picture\crime.jpg_

Comment: You cannot access a file from your PC to Android emulator as Windows will prevent any unauthorized access to folders in C Drive.

Comment: @UmangBurman i change image address and now `Log` is _image: D:\test\cat.jpg_ but still does not show

Comment: Yes because you cannot access windows from your device or emulator, they are both different OS. Are you getting the path of your image from WAMP server?

Comment: @UmangBurman i don't know what is WAMP , but i wrote web service with JAX-RS and i store image address from my pc in Oracle instead of image itself and i want retrieve image from address in android

Comment: I'm sorry but it's just not possible. You can store the image itself then get the URL and pass it to Picasso then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Picasso.get().load("http://whereyourimageis.com/yourimage.png").into(imageView);
```

Try this one. I am referring to the documentation: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You can use like below way to LOAD FILE FROM SDCARD/Device storage: in your case, the file URL is located in your Windows Drive which do not allow unauthorized access. You can decide to load from web or storage:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView3);
```

Make sure you are passing fullpath of image

read from [documentaion](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Hope it's useful.